# Trouble handling hidden element with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Every time I run this code, I get an issue reaching to the targeted page. The site requires post request parameter to be filled in to reach the page where I am after. However, using get request it was good to go until it hits "Var4" parameter within my code. Inspecting element I could see that it indicates as hidden. If i left the hidden parameter blank then it redirects to another location. So, satisfying this thing to get to the targeted page is beyond my capability. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.infocomm.org/cps/rde/xchg/infocomm/hs.xsl/memberdirectory.htm')

Var1='Professional Services Providers'
Var2='AUSTRALIA'
Var3='0'
Var4='1'

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="mas_type"]').send_keys(Var1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="mas_cntr"]').send_keys(Var2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="OtherCriteria"]').send_keys(Var3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="DoMemberSearch"]').send_keys(Var4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```

Element for the hidden stuffs which should be applicable for "Var4":

```
    <form name="searchform" id="searchform" action="memberdirectory.htm" method="post" onsubmit="return Checkform();">
<input type="hidden" id="DoMemberSearch" name="DoMemberSearch" value="1">
<div class="login block-type-a block">
```

Comment: Can you show the `html` surrounding this `input`? Since truly hidden fields don't show up on the page, my guess is that element is hidden within the actual element you want to be sending keys to.

Comment: Thanks mrfreester, for your answer. I just updated with the partial portion of the form. Hope it will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround, you can try execute javascript with selenium.

For example, to unhide element

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('DoMemberSearch').type = 'text';")
```

or set value directly

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('DoMemberSearch').value = '%s';" % Var4)
```

Comment: Thanks SergeiZ, for your answer. I need to know something about the expression you've written above. why these two expressions (document.get--) and Semicolon before the end of the expression? Executing your method I found no error so I suppose it is leading me to the right direction.

Comment: In these expressions we are executing JavaScript directly in browser, to manipulate with web page, semicolon in JavaScript serve to separate statements.

Comment: In second expression we use Python string formatting to assign value of Var4 to '%s' in expression. More about it here - https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thanks for everything, SergeiZ.

Comment: @SMth80 Generally speaking, if you can have your **selenium** test actually follow a user path that would be better. Since **Selenium** is meant to mimic a typical user, it doesn't have simple methods for manipulating the **html**. I'd avoid executing **javascript** when possible, but this is the only way to do what you're asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could not sendkeys to a hidden element, what you can do is to use javascript to send the value

probably something like this

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('DoMemberSearch').value='1')
```